# Entity is not mapped exception when entity used in EJB module

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss, ejb, persistence

I've got a problem with entity mapping.

Here is JBoss containing several modules, one of them contains package with entity mappings annotated with

```
@Entity 
@Table(name = "PG_ATTR_A")
public class PgAttrA
// declaration omitted
}
```

In separate package and separate EJB module I have a DAO to access this data

```
@Stateless
@Clustered
public class PgAttrDao implements PgAttrDaoLocal, PgAttrDaoRemote {

    @PersistenceContext (unitName = "Persistence_Unit")
    EntityManager entityManager;

    public List<PgAttrA> find(...) {
        Query query = entityManager.createQuery("FROM PgAttrA WHERE ..skiped..");
        // set some parameters, skipped
        return query.getResultList();
    }
}
```

Content of persistence.xml
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd" version="1.0">

```
<persistence-unit name="Persistence_Unit" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <jta-data-source>DS</jta-data-source>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="false"/>          
        <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

The problem is DAO seems to don't know about ORM declared in PgAttr class.

I've got this particular exception:

> Exception occurred in target VM:
>   org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: PgAttrA is not mapped
>   [FROM PgAttrA WHERE ..skiped..]  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: PgAttrA is not mapped
>   [FROM PgAttrA WHERE ..skiped..]

I have some other DAO accessing this particular entity in the same module as the entity itself and it works like a charm. I just do not have access to sources of that DAO to add some new features.

So the question is why my DAO doesn't see the mapping and what should I do to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a matter of fact I've just missed jar-file declaration in persistence.xml

so I've added

```
<jar-file>../jar_where_persistence_declared.jar</jar-file>
```

just after

```
<jta-data-source>DS</jta-data-source>
```

and problem has gone

Answer (score 0):

if you use JPQL change your query to:

```
 Query query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT p FROM PgAttrA p WHERE ..skiped..");
```

JPQL queries example from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbtl.html)

If you use HQL :

```
Query query = entityManager.createQuery("FROM PgAttrA AS p WHERE ..skiped..");
```

HQLQueries example from [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_query_language.htm)

if your problem is not solved inspect your `persistence.xml`,

Comment: @user1455836  why you use  `<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>`
you can use     `<provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>` it is easier

Comment: this declaration is used throughout the server so I'll better stick with it
Meanwhile, thank you for idea of inspecting persistence.xml, I've managed to find answer due to it.

Comment: @user1455836 I edited my answer you can upvote it or accept it to help other users